# Custom XCTestCase Class- Tests aren't executed

Tags: xcode, unit-testing

This is probably really easy / stupid, but I can't find it why it's happening.

I've created a custom class, which inherits XCTestCase. When trying to run the tests, the tests in that class aren't executed.

This is my class:

```
@interface TNMediaBarTest : XCTestCase

@end

@implementation TNMediaBarTest

- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];
    // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class. }

- (void)tearDown {
    // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
    [super tearDown]; }

- (void)TNMediaBarLocationButtonTest {
    TNMediaBar *mediaBar = [[TNMediaBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    XCTAssertNil(mediaBar.location, @"There's junk in location property after initialization");

    [mediaBar locationButtonTapped];

    XCTAssertNotNil(mediaBar.location, @"Location is empty after tapping on location button");

    [mediaBar locationButtonTapped];

    XCTAssertNil(mediaBar.location, @"Location is not empty after tapping on location button a second time"); }
```

But I get:

```
Executed 0 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.000 (0.001) seconds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prefix your test method's name with `test` like:

```
- (void)testName
```

In your case, rename `TNMediaBarLocationButtonTest` to something like:

```
- (void)testMediaBarLocationButton
```

Comment: Yep, I knew it was something of this sort. Thank you.